# Raspberry pi interfacing with windows PC

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3

Hello Friends,
               I have a raspberry pi powered with Raspbian OS. I want to create a device which will perform some action like "open calculator ,open notepad,etc" on windows pc by commanding from a raspberry pi. So my problem is how to establish communication between raspberry pi and another windows pc ?
                 If i use VNC and SSH service, can i invoke other programs remotely on pc ?

Comment: There are several non-trivial ways to execute this requirement. Writing a remote listener on Windows "Server" which receives commands and execute Win32 API is one way. Easiest way to test assumptions and create prototype is using [Powershell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/core-powershell/web-access?view=powershell-5.1). Login into web access from Raspberry and trigger commands on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `netcat`, also known as `nc` which is included in most Linux distros and is available for Windows.

All you would do on the Windows box is get your IP address with:

```
ipconfig
```

Then you would start listening on some random port, say 5000 because that has no security restrictions and pass whatever arrives on that port to CMD.EXE for execution:

```
nc -l -p 5000 -e CMD.EXE
```

Then, on your Raspberry Pi, you would just do:

```
nc <WINDOWS_IP_ADDRESS> 5000
```

Now you can type Windows commands in your Rasperry Pi terminal for execution on the Windows box:

```
DIR
NOTEPAD
```

---

There is a *"cheatsheet"* [here](https://www.sans.org/security-resources/sec560/netcat_cheat_sheet_v1.pdf) and I am using the technique in the section entitled *"Backdoor Shells"*.

---

Note that this is a big security hole, but if it is just for yourself playing around on a private network, it is nice and simple.